# Need formula to find the Highest value among group of entries, if conditions are fullfilled

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have certain Daily Data on Daily sheet and I need formula Weekly data sheet, suppose 1st week of 2014 starts from 1st Jan 2014, hence on weekly data I need formula which will search that corresponding data in daily sheet and returns the Value in corresponding cell on weekly data sheet. I hope I have make understood my question properly

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Title makes it sound like a MAXIF or MAXIFS type of situation which is available in excel 2016.  However you are tagged with excel 2007 so you will need to use an array formula or AGGREGATE function which I do not know if they are available in 2007.

Comment: 1. Does the daily sheet already contain the week number values, so those can be used to identify records for the weekly sheet?  2. Open Value for the week is the Open Value for the 1st day in that week number?  3. Close Value for the week is Close Value for the last day of that week number?  4. High Price and Low Price for the week are the highest High Price and lowest Low Price from that week number's daily values?  5. Date for the week data is the date of the 1st daily record for that week number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel 2007, your best bet for MAXIFS and MINIFS functionality is to use SUMPRODUCT.

For your "high price" formula in cell C3, use:

```
    =SUMPRODUCT(MAX('Daily Data'!$C$2:$C$37*
(('Daily Data'!$A$2:$A$37>=$A3)*('Daily Data'!$A$2:$A$37<$A3+7))))
```

and for your "low price" formula in cell D3, use:

```
    =SUMPRODUCT(MIN('Daily Data'!$D$2:$D$37*
(('Daily Data'!$A$2:$A$37>=$A3)*('Daily Data'!$A$2:$A$37<$A3+7)*-10000+10001))`)
```

The way the SUMPRODUCT formula works is explained here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e

The first function (For high price), works by going row by row down the whole list taking these two conditions ">=$A3" and "

The min function works similarly, however, we can't use 0s because MIN would return the 0. So instead, we take the true (1) and multiply it by -10000. Then we add 10001. So now all the ones out of the specified date range are 10000x too large, and all the ones inside the date range are at regular scale. So when we take the MIN the ones outside of the date range are way too large to have any chance of being the low price.

Comment: Perfect !!! This formulas really works, I would reuqest you sir, if you can show formula for Weekly Data sheet cell A3, B3 AND E3 . Cell B3 will always be the first value among list, for example for CELL B3 value will be cell B4 valu from Daily Data SHeet and Cell E3 of Weekly data value will be cell B6 value from Daily Data and so on.

Comment: Can you ask that as a separate question. Should be just one question.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I have done accordingly please find the attached link https://superuser.com/questions/1434732/need-formula-to-convert-daily-dates-into-corresponding-week-number-in-a-year