# WEEKNUM produces the wrong result for January 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

On my data sheet, DAILY DATA SHEET, I use formula `=WEEKNUM(A3)`, and it's returning `1`.  Actually, 1st Jan 2014 is a continuation of the last week of 2013.  So instead, it should return `53` and not `1`.

I need a formula to copy the first date from the daily data sheet, which starts the new week series, to the column A cells.  Please also note that there is some problem on cell E109, if anyone can spot what that might be.

<sub>*(Click images for larger view)*</sub>

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify - you want the first day of week1 to be the first Monday of the new year?

Comment: A year is typically considered to be 52 weeks (364 vs 365 days, so only 1 day error).  The calendar in the first image shows only 2 days from the previous year in the first week.  Wouldn't it be more accurate to say the last two days of the previous year are part of the first week of the new year?  If you credit 5 days of January to week 53 of the previous year, you're likely to end up with a short current year (51 weeks).  So you'll have much less uniformity year to year.

Comment: You ask three separate questions in your post and attached screenshots which are hard to read. Please split your post, one per question, and make sure they are easy to understand.

Comment: For `weeknum` read Microsoft help [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/isoweeknum-function-1c2d0afe-d25b-4ab1-8894-8d0520e90e0e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: If you look at Wolfgang Jacques' 1st link, it describes the two standard definitions for the 1st week of the year (week containing Jan 1 or week containing the 1st Thurs of the year).  Both definitions would result in the same calculation you're seeing.  To do anything else will require something custom and non-standard.  Before people invest time tackling that, can you confirm that you're constrained to your definition in the question.  Just want to rule out the possibility that you might be basing the requirement on a misconception about the 1st week of the year.

Comment: The result you see is **correct**, according to the definition being used for `WEEKNUM`.  To obtain the results you want, you need to provide the precise definition of weeknumber that you want to utilize.