# Index match function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've use INDEX MATCH formula for my case like this:

```
=INDEX(D3:D4;MATCH(SMALL(C3:C4;1);C3:C4,0))
```

In column C is date and in column D is time. I want to get oldest time of odlest date.
With above formula I get the oldest date and time in the row of first matched date.

In example

```
C          D
1.1.2019   14:00
1.1.2019   13:00
3.4.2019   10:00
```

I get 1.1.2019 14:00 and I need to get 1.1.2019 13:00

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with out using INDEX.

You can use `MIN` to get the oldest date, then `MINIFS` to find the oldest time of the oldest date, then join them bother together.

The below is turning them into a string:

```
=TEXT(MIN(C2:C4),"DD/MM/YYYY")&" "&TEXT(TEXT(MINIFS(D2:D4,C2:C4,MIN(C2:C4)),"HH:MM"),"HH:MM")
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer but I can't use minifs because I have users which work on that document with excel version prior minifs function implemented. Can I work around something with index and match or only solution is array formula? And actually I don't need as a result date + time. I only need the oldest time of the oldest date. Oldest date I get easily in separate cell and the time is problem cause it is conditional minimum

Answer (score 0):

As excel prior 2016 doesn't have minifs function if you don't want to use array formula you could use sumproduct. Solution for my problem was this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MIN(D3:D5*((C3:C5=MIN(C3:C5))*-10000+10001)))
```

Reference
[Need formula to find the Highest value among group of entries, if conditions are fullfilled](https://superuser.com/questions/1433501/need-formula-to-find-the-highest-value-among-group-of-entries-if-conditions-are)